# Regular expression with condition on inner expressions

Tags: swift, regex

I would like to build a regular expression for replacing a sentence with "per" when it should be (a readable version of a sentence with quantities).

That is:

- "3/unit" must match
- "unit/3" must match
- "feet/second" must match
- "05/07" must not match

I know how to create something like "\D+/\D+".
But how can I build a regex saying "not both right and left expressions match \D+" ?

Comment: Maybe `^(?![0-9]+/[0-9]+$)[^/]+/[^/]+$`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?![0-9]+/[0-9]+$)[^/]+/[^/]+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MDaab7/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?![0-9]+/[0-9]+$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are one or more digits, `/`, one or more digits and end of string position immediately to the right of the current location
- `[^/]+/[^/]+` - one or more chars other than `/`, a `/` char, and then one or more chars other than `/`
- `$` - end of string.